# CSS: flex-wrap creates a large space that grows with number of elements added to grid within it

Tags: css

In the example below there is a large red gap, which I think should not be there, here on referred to as "gap". It occurs in Firefox and in Chrome. So I would like to correct my understanding of flex/grid containers.

The strange thing is this space grows depending on the number of items placed in `#CONTAINER`. If you half the number of items in it, say to 4 (111 to 444), then the space will half, if you added items to it the space will grow.

I just don't understand where this gap is coming from, why is the gap is growing and shrinking. I have determine it occurs when the `flex-wrap: wrap` is applied to `#CARD` from trial and error. So this post is not about "fixing the code below so it behaves a certain way". It's about understanding where is the space coming from? Why does adding items to `#CONTAINER` make the space after it grow?

Note : I require the `flex-wrap: wrap` in my real code, this is just a minimal reproducible example.

```css
#CARD {
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 8px;
}

#SECTION {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#CONTAINER {
  background: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(100%, 268px), 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div id="CARD"><!-- gray -->
  <div id="SECTION"><!-- red -->
    <div id="CONTAINER"><!-- green -->
      <div>
        <div>111</div>
        <div>222</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>333</div>
        <div>444</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>555</div>
        <div>666</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>777</div>
        <div>888</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the red is filling the height i think so what if you add flex-wrap to the red div

Comment: A red section's must not wrap, the gray card's are supposed to wrap.

Comment: What I find interesting is that, on my device at least, the total height (excluding the padding) is always `144px` with the four items.
Adding two more (total six) makes it always `216px`.
Removing two (total two) makes it always `72px`.
Thus, every item seems to account for `36px` of total height.

Comment: Without additional properties applied, it seems that the grid (`CONTAINER`) is calculated as having one item in each row (a row per item). The flexbox around that (`SECTION`) then sizes itself based on that height. Then the default `align-items: stretch` is applied to the grid, and it becomes the full width of the flexbox; however, the flexbox does not change its height. So it's as if the flexbox is using the maximum height of the grid, but setting any explicit width on the grid changes the layout calculation, as a width is known beforehand.

Comment: My above comment was partially covered by Ricardo Silva's answer, and the first part more properly explained by vals.

Comment: I've written a partial answer based on the Flexbox spec. Not sure how helpful it will be in its current state, but it should be a good start. I do plan to finish it within the next week or so :)

Comment: Overhauled my answer. **I have found a likely cause** for the behavior, or at least got very near it.

Comment: To fix the issue, remove the `flex-wrap: wrap` property from the #CARD element but if youre code require it then you can add an extra container to wrap your #SECTION element, and apply the `flex-wrap: wrap` to that new container instead of #CARD. This way, the gap won't affect your main layout.

Comment: @run_the_race, **I've found the root cause!** See my updated answer. In short: the grid container's height is calculated differently between the two modes, and this height is then used as the final height of the flex container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the flex container depends on its contents in this case, which is the height of the grid container. **However, the height of the grid container will varying depending on the width it is laid out with, which in this case varies depending on whether it is a single-line or multi-line flex container.**

With a single-line flex container, the grid container's width is considered "definite", and its height is calculated by laying it out with that width.

With a multi-line flex container, the grid container's width is not definite, so the height is calculated by laying out as if it had `width: fit-content` applied.

This calculated height is then used as the height for the flex container.

Thus, the grid will always be the width of the flex container's inner cross size, which is the width of the flex container's containing block less margin, border, and padding. **However, because of the way definite sizes differ between single-line and multi-line flex containers, the height depends on whether it is a single-line or multi-line container!**

Any lower children (including the grid container, if there are elements in between it and the wrapping flex container) are the laid out normally within this child.

Summary of the effect of `width: fit-content` on the grid container:

With `width: fit-content` and using `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`, each row will only contain one item, and therefore there will be one row for every item, which means that the total height in that case is simply the sum of heights of the items in the grid. This is what causes the total height (grid + gap) to be sized linearly based on the number of items in it.

Without `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`, the grid will have different behavior, which doesn't cause this behavior in the flexbox. See my  [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/darrylnoakes/pen/MWqXvQy) of the different combinations (default width + `auto-fill`, default width + fixed column count, `fit-content` + `auto-fill`, `fit-content` + fixed column count).

---

Based on normal grid behavior, the intuitive expectation is that there should be no gap, and, without wrapping enabled, it does indeed behave as expected. However, the layout calculation differences involved when using wrapping say otherwise.

1. Enabling wrapping on only the outer flex container results in the behavior you described.
2. Enabling wrapping on only the inner flex container results in similar behavior: the card ends up with the same height, but the grid fills the inner flex container.
3. Using just a wrapping flex container around the grid results in the grid being that same "max height", like in 2.

In your case (1), we have a grid container, inside a single-line flex container, inside a multi-line flex container.

**As seen in 3, the behavior manifests even with just a single flex container.** A simplified case for exploring!

Note:
The grid rows, because they are implicit, share out the available vertical space.
This means that while the parent is still higher than it would normally be, if the grid forms multiple rows due to lack of width, it's not *as* noticeable as in the case with multiple elements.
However, it is still the same core behavior.

So "problem statement":
For some reason, the height of the flex container is being calculated as the height of the grid with each item on its own row, and staying at that height.

[CodePen repro](https://codepen.io/darrylnoakes/pen/MWqGvBp) to follow along with or just fiddle around in.

---

Into spec land!

For reference:

A "definite size" is defined as follows:

> A size that can be determined without performing layout; that is, a `<length>`, a measure of text (without consideration of line-wrapping), a size of the initial containing block, or a  or other formula (such the “stretch-fit” sizing of non-replaced blocks [CSS2]) that is resolved solely against definite sizes.
>
> Additionally, the size of the containing block of an absolutely positioned element is always definite with respect to that element.

**That "stretch-fit" sizing part is the key here**; it is what causes block-level elements to stretch to the width of their containing block. As the size of the initial containing block is definite, and this "stretch-fit" is resolved against the initial containing block for the flex container (it works recursively through through multiple levels of nesting, obviously), **the flex container has a definite width**.

The "main size" of a flex container is the size *along* the its main axis, and the "main size property" is the property which controls it (`width` or `height`). As in this case the container is using columns, the main dimension is height.
The cross size is the other dimension. Width, in this case.

The Flex Layout Algorithm defines some extra cases:

> [9.8. Definite and Indefinite Sizes](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-flexbox/#definite-sizes)
>
> Although CSS Sizing [CSS-SIZING-3] defines definite and indefinite lengths, Flexbox has several additional cases where a length can be considered ***definite***:
>
> 1. If the flex container has a definite main size, then the post-flexing main sizes of its flex items are treated as definite.
> 2. If a flex item’s flex basis is definite, then its post-flexing main size is also definite.
> 3. If a single-line flex container has a definite cross size, the automatic preferred outer cross size of any stretched flex items is the flex container’s inner cross size (clamped to the flex item’s min and max cross size) and is considered definite.
> 4. Once the cross size of a flex line has been determined, the cross sizes of items in auto-sized flex containers are also considered definite for the purpose of layout; see step 11.

**Point 3 is the important one for us.**

Now, into the depths of the beast that is the [Flex Layout Algorithm](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-flexbox/#layout-algorithm)...

---

[9.2. Line Length Determination](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-flexbox/#line-sizing)

The end result of this is the main size (height, in this case) of the flex container, i.e., the length of the lines.

> 2. **Determine the available main and cross space for the flex items.** For each dimension, if that dimension of the flex container’s content box is a definite size, use that;

**Yes, the cross size (width) of the flex container is definite,** and is the width of the containing block.

The main size (height) is infinite and therefore indefinite.

> if that dimension of the flex container is being sized under a min or max-content constraint, the available space in that dimension is that constraint;

Nope, neither of those constraints.

> otherwise, subtract the flex container’s margin, border, and padding from the space available to the flex container in that dimension and use that value. This might result in an infinite value.

The main dimension is vertical, which gives us infinite space available in that direction.

> 3. **Determine the flex base size and hypothetical main size of each item:**

> A. If the item has a definite used flex basis, that’s the flex base size.

The flex basis defaults to `auto`, which "retrieves the value of the main size property as the used `flex-basis`."
"If that value is itself `auto`, then the used value is `content`," which "indicates an automatic size based on the flex item’s content."

So, no, there is not a "definite used flex basis," as it depends on the content, which will require layout to be performed.

Point "B" does not apply (the items have no preferred aspect ratio).

Point "C" does not apply (the flex container is not being sized under a min-content or max-content constraint).

Point "D" does not apply (the flex item’s inline axis is not parallel to the main axis).

So, "E":

> E. Otherwise, size the item into the available space using its used flex basis in place of its main size, treating a value of `content` as `max-content`. If a cross size is needed to determine the main size (e.g. when the flex item’s main size is in its block axis, or when it has a preferred aspect ratio) and the flex item’s cross size is `auto` and not definite, in this calculation use `fit-content` as the flex item’s cross size. The flex base size is the item’s resulting main size.

***This is the core of the issue!***

From the earlier note about definite sizes:

> If a single-line flex container has a definite cross size, the automatic preferred outer cross size of any stretched flex items is the flex container’s inner cross size (clamped to the flex item’s min and max cross size) and is considered definite.

The cross size of the flex container is definite, yes. So, if it's a *single-line* flex container (wrapping is not enabled), the outer cross size (width) of the item is the width of the flex container *and is definite!*
**So, with a single-line flex container, the main size of the grid (its height) is what it would be under normal layout, with an automatic width**

**If it is a multi-line container, then it uses `fit-content` as the cross size (width):**
The grid container's main size is in its block axis and its cross size (width) is `auto` and not definite (as it is a multi-line flex container). Therefore, `fit-content` is used as the grid container's width when calculating its height.

[`fit-content`](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-sizing-4/#valdef-width-fit-content) is "essentially `fit-content(stretch)` i.e. min(`max-content`, max(`min-content`, `stretch`))."

`stretch` attempts "to match the size of the box’s margin box to the size of its containing block."
The referenced "stretch-fit size":

> The size a box would take if its outer size filled the available space in the given axis; in other words, the stretch fit into the available space, if that is definite. Undefined if the available space is indefinite.

As we are working in the inline axis, the available space for the grid is the width of the flex container. So the width of flex container unless it is really narrow, in which case it will be the `min-content` size of the grid (which in this case is one item in each row, all word wrap opportunities taken).

The max then is that size versus the `max-content` size of the grid, which in this case is one item in each row with each item as wide as it wants.

> ***max-content inline size***
> The box’s “ideal” size in the inline axis. Usually the narrowest inline size it could take while fitting around its contents if none of the soft wrap opportunities within the box were taken.

**So, tada! The resulting height of the grid in this calculation is the total height we are seeing in the "misbehaving" cases.**

"The flex base size [what we were trying to find in this section] is the item's resulting main size [one of the two heights we just calculated]."

As no min and max sizes are present, the last two paragraphs don't apply; the flex base size and the hypothetical main size are the same.

> 4. **Determine the main size of the flex container** using the rules of the formatting context in which it participates.

Its main size is its height, as said earlier. The formatting context is plain old Flow Layout in this case, where the height is based on content; it will be the width of its containing block.
So, as there is only the one item in this case, it will be one of the two heights we calculated above.

**If it is a single-line flex container, the value is the height of the grid container when laid out with the full width of the flex container.**
**If it is a multi-line flex-container, the value is the height of the grid container when laid out with `width: fit-content` applied.**

This is the difference in grid heights we are seeing, and directly affects the main size (height) if the flex container.

**This is the final used height of the flex container!**
This is it! This is why having wrapping enabled affects the height: it stops the item's cross size being considered definite, which means it's height is calculated differently,

---

[9.3. Main Size Determination](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-flexbox/#main-sizing)

This is the main sizes of the *items*, including resolution of flexible lengths (involves `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow`).

> 5. **Collect flex items into flex lines:**

As the main size is calculated based on the content (the grid container) in this case, we only need a single line. We also only have one item in this case, so it will always be just one line.

> 6. Resolve the flexible lengths of all the flex items to find their used main size. See § 9.7 Resolving Flexible Lengths.

As the main size of the flex container is currently based on the content, the items' sizes will not change. **So the used main size of the grid container is the same as its hypothetical main size/flex base size, which is what we calculated earlier.**

---

[9.4. Cross Size Determination](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-flexbox/#cross-sizing)

> 7. **Determine the *hypothetical cross size* of each item** by performing layout as if it were an in-flow block-level box with the used main size and the given available space, treating `auto` as `fit-content`.

This would be like laying out the grid with `width: fit-content` applied (there is no width specified, so it uses `auto`, which is treated as `fit-content`).
See the notes about section 9.2 ("Line Length Determination").

> 8. **Calculate the cross size of each flex line.**

> If the flex container is single-line and has a definite cross size, the cross size of the flex line is the flex container’s inner cross size.

**If it is a single-line container (i.e., wrapping is not enabled), this applies.** It has a definite cross size (see the earlier note about definite sizes). So the cross size of the sole flex line in that case would be the flex container's inner cross size, which is the width of its containing block less margin, border, and padding.

**If is a multi-line container:**

> ... for each flex line:

We only have the one.

Step 1 does not apply (the grid container's inline-axis is not parallel to the main-axis).

> 2. ..., find the largest outer hypothetical cross size.

This is the maximum value of the sizes found in 7, so it's going to be the width of the grid container when laid out with `width: fit-content` applied.

> 3. The used cross-size of the flex line is the largest of the numbers found in the previous two steps and zero.

So, still the width of the grid container under `width: fit-content`.

Now we have the used cross-size of the line (that same width).

> 10. **Handle 'align-content: stretch'.** If the flex container has a definite cross size, align-content is stretch, and the sum of the flex lines' cross sizes is less than the flex container’s inner cross size, ...

Yes, it has a definite cross size, align-content is the default value stretch, and the sum of the flex lines' cross sizes is less than the flex container’s inner cross size: the sole line's cross size is the `width: fit-content` width of the grid, while the flex container's inner cross size is the width of its containing block less margin and padding.

> increase the cross size of each flex line by equal amounts such that the sum of their cross sizes exactly equals the flex container’s inner cross size.

There is only one line, so it simply expands to fill the flex container. The cross size of the line is now the full width of the flex container.

Point 10 does not apply.

> 11. **Determine the used cross size of each flex item.** If a flex item has `align-self: stretch`, its computed cross size property is `auto`, and neither of its cross-axis margins are `auto`, ...

Yes, this applies.

> ... the used outer cross size is the used cross size of its flex line, clamped according to the item’s used min and max cross sizes.

**So, the grid container will be stretched horizontally to the full width of the flex container.** This applies with both single- and multi-line flex containers.

> If the flex item has `align-self: stretch`, redo layout for its contents, treating this used size as its definite cross size so that percentage-sized children can be resolved.
>
> Note that this step does not affect the main size of the flex item, even if it has a preferred aspect ratio.

**So the item (the grid container) will have layout redone for its contents, but its main size (height) will not change!**

This section has not actually made any differences based on whether the flex container is single-line or multi-line, but it shows that the width is always the same and that part about redoing layout is important.

---

Thus, the grid will always be the width of the flex container's inner cross size, which is the width of the flex container's containing block less margin, border, and padding.

However, because of the definite sizing clause, the height depends on whether it is a single-line or multi-line container!

All these definite/indefinite sizes conditionals why setting an explicit width fixes the issue.
Setting an explicit width means that it is used instead of `fit-content` when calculating the main size of the grid container, which gives the expected result.

Mystery solved!

Comment: Wow very indepth answer, thank you for digging deep. What I did not get from the answer is why the spaces grows linearly as more children are added?

Comment: That is due to the height being calculated by performing layout on the grid container as if it had `width: fit-content` applied. With the grid config in this case, that means that there is one item per row, or, in other words, one row per item. Which means that every item adds its height to the total.

Comment: I'll be editing it later to improve flow and readability, as it's rather cobbled together at the moment. I'll include that clarification. Thanks for pointing it out that I hadn't been explicit about that.

Comment: Found the root issue and updated my answer. Mystery solved!

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive, and for cracking the mystery! Well Done!! I do struggle to understand it. To me its a bit of a bug, maybe after calculating the layout, they should see that there is more than 1 item per row, and the height estimation calculation based on `fit-content` is incorrect, and hence correct itself.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a circular dependency of sizes, so it doesn't end up as expected. Maybe you could contact someone in spec work and ask them about it :). There are quite a lot of compromises made for the sake of having actually usable efficiency, so there are cases like this where it behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: Oh, congrats on +500. But I don't think this reward is fair. After all, I found a solution to the problem, I spent my time on it, and in general - digging for reasons is of course easier if you know the answer. I am especially impressed by the citation of standards, even those that are not relevant to the problem - maybe this affected the reward?.. But I think that it is `auto-fill` that causes the problem, not the `fit-content` width . You can make sure of this by simply changing the value `auto-fill` to any other. For example `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(min(100%, 268px), 1fr));`

Comment: "Mystery solved!", but did you solve it? But this will be a lesson for me, maybe I will publish my answers a little later))
P.S. An interesting fact, the author of the question did not even look at my codepen with explanations.
Thank you for attention. 

Comment: Yes, but `auto-fill` affects the width of the grid when using `width: fit-content`. So it is really two sides of the same coin. The flex algorithm uses `fit-content`, and the grid's specific behavior under that is due to `auto-fill`.

Comment: Here's a CodePen with the four different combos: https://codepen.io/darrylnoakes/pen/MWqXvQy

Comment: @imhvost, I've given your answer an upvote, as it _was_ useful to me; it provided some initial information that let me get going a lot faster.

Comment: I'm simply saying that the cause of the behavior is that the Flex Layout algorithm uses `fit-content` in this case, and the grid happens to have a different height with that when using `auto-fill`. In fact, I actually stated in the beginning of my answer that it is in part due to `autof-fill` (I will clarify it further, though).

Comment: @imhvost `But I don't think this reward is fair. After all, I found a solution to the problem, I spent my time on it, and in general - digging for reasons is of course easier if you know the answer.` I also found a solution; I spent a total of at least 10 hours on it; and I didn't know the answer beforehand, I researched.

Comment: @imhvost `I am especially impressed by the citation of standards, even those that are not relevant to the problem - maybe this affected the reward?..` Of course I cited the spec; it's the only thing I could find that accurately describes the algorithm in its full detail. I don't know of any I cited that aren't relevant; if there is anything, please actually point it out. And yes, it probably did affect the bounty, as the OP wanted a reputable source, of which the spec is one of the foremost.

Comment: I did my research, and provided an answer. I don't believe I did anything hurtful or mean to you. This is SO: we write answers to a question, and the asker chooses one that they feel answers their question.

Comment: @imhvost I also spent about 6 hours on this, but sadly I only found some regular behavior about combined `grid`, `flex`, `auto-fill`, `wrapping` and etc, but not a explicit answer based on an official document. After reading @Darryl's this answer, I thought it is the correct one. And the asker doesn't want to solve the issue, he wanted to know why. Hope we all can be happy to learn a lot through this journey!

Answer (score 1):

It should be added to `#SECTION`:

```css
#SECTION{
  width: 100%;
}
```

I think any `width` value prevents the auto placement algorithm from creating extra rows. `min-width:100%` also works. Yes, it looks like a hack.

**Update:**
Some experiments confirm the idea of creation **implicit grid** https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#implicit-grid , namely the meaning of `auto-fill`. Confirmation of this is set to another value instead `auto-fill` / `auto-fit`. Or zeroing `grid-auto-rows` (but unfortunately is breaking the grid on newlines):

```css
#CONTAINER {
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 0;
}
```

Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/GRXQjOJ)

**Update 2:** Also @Darryl Noakes are absolutely right about `width: fit-content`. Here is the confirmation: [codepen](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/jOvKbRR). `auto-fill` cells have exactly this height. This, by the way, explains why this space grows depending on the number of items placed in.

```css
#CARD {
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 8px;
}

#SECTION {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:100%;
}

#CONTAINER {
  background: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(100%, 268px), 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div id="CARD"><!-- gray -->
  <div id="SECTION"><!-- red -->
    <div id="CONTAINER"><!-- green -->
      <div>
        <div>111</div>
        <div>222</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>333</div>
        <div>444</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>555</div>
        <div>666</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>777</div>
        <div>888</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why adding width: 100% to #SECTION works?

Comment: @run_the_race , added my thoughts on this to the answer

Comment: Thanks for adding "I think any width value prevents the auto placement algorithm from creating extra rows. min-width:100% also works.", I still don't understand what it means though.

Comment: I added a little to the answer

Comment: At least in the case provided by the OP, the grid itself has the correct height, at least in the actual final layout. The implicit grid means that implicit rows are created when there are too many items to fit on the current rows; the grid fits its height to its contents. It does _not_ mean that they are always there and the grid is therefore that height.

Comment: However, for the flex container's calculations, the grid has layout performed on it as if it had `width: fit-content` applied if no width or width contraints are specified. With `auto-fill`, this means that every item will be on its own row.

Comment: @Darryl Noakes , you are absolutely right about `width: fit-content`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering where the red gap comes from, it's the result of the grid-template-columns CSS property. Specifically, the first argument of the repeat value in this property is responsible for creating the gap. According to [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-grid/#auto-repeat), the gap is introduced when using the auto-repeat feature. When the first argument is set to auto-fill, the gap will be automatically applied to your grid container.

> If the grid container has a definite or maximal size in the relevant axis, then the number of repetitions is the largest possible positive integer that does not cause the grid to overflow its grid container. Treating each track as its maximal track sizing function (each independent value used to define grid-template-rows or grid-template-columns), if that is definite. Otherwise, as its minimum track sizing function, and taking grid-gap into account. If any number of repetitions would overflow, then the repetition is 1. Otherwise, if the grid container has a definite minimal size in the relevant axis, the number of repetitions is the smallest possible positive integer that fulfills that minimum requirement. Otherwise, the specified track list repeats only once.

Comment: Then why does it only apply when using a wrapping flex container, and not at any other time (not being sarcastic)? Is it because it changes whether there is a "maximal" or "definite" size somewhere?

Comment: This simply defines how many columns the grid has. It does not create a gap in and of itself.

Comment: It will apply when the grid is layed out with `width: fit-content`, though. So while it does affect it rather indirectly, it is not itself the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think i find a possible solution, its because you are using flexbox-based grid system, that means grid systems work by taking flexbox back to the familiar world of float-based layouts.

The `flex-wrap:wrap;` attribute means the each element can be in one column and the `#CONTAINER` add extra height for the `#SECTION`  to make room for each element.

Read more in this link: [flexbox-based grid system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items#how_do_flexbox-based_grid_systems_work)

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying. I read the link, I already understand how flex works (well I think I do), but did learn something new: `visibility: collapse`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are combining flex with grid and within it you are wrapping on the column, which effectively will do is to layout the items top to bottom and when there is no height it will wrap into rows. But if you check, your grid already does that but wrapping rows into columns. So the container will occupy the space for the items unwrapped on the column if you don't set a fixed height.

If you remove [the column wrapping it should work](https://play.tailwindcss.com/H8M8QFFPki?file=css) because the grid does the wrapping from rows into columns.

You see that [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/IhOsoUzUKD?file=css). I set the red container to 1px height, now the items are force to wrap into rows.

Comment: In the #CARD there is one item, what is wrapping "into rows" as you state? Thanks for the answer, but as mentioned in the question: "Note : I require the flex-wrap: wrap in my real code, this is just a minimal reproducible example."

Comment: that is exactly the point. #CARD has nothing to wrap into rows, so the size will always be the maximum height when all the content is condensed from the grid, which is when they all stack. and that is why the "gap" "grow and shrinks", but nothing is really happening. just the grid is pushing the items into rows. I am not sure what the correct result should look like if you share it I can look into. But I am pretty positive this is the correct behavior for flex column wrapping if you don't set fixed heights.